# How to check if number is above Integer.MAX_VALUE in Java, when adding to it some other number?

Tags: java

I have a problem when I add some number to the maximum of Integer, I am no longer above the maximum because the number changes to Integer.MIN_VALUE + added valued -1, how should I than check it ? 
`

```
        int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int x = max +100;
        if (x > max){
            System.out.println(x + "x is not bigger, so it wont be printed.");

        }


    }
}`
```

Comment: `long x = max + 100L;`

Comment: An `int` value is never above `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, by definition, so it's not clear what you actually want to check for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of methods depending on what you want to do.

1. If you are looking to add a number to an `int` and want to know if it overflows, then use `Math.addExact`. It throws an `ArithmeticException` which you can catch if you want to take action.
2. If you want to safely add a value and then compare to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` then use a `long` instead. By definition no `int` is ever larger than the maximum value.

So I'd suggest

```
try {
    int x = Math.addExact(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 100);
} catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
    System.out.println("x has overflowed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick feedback

Comment: Nice it works, finally I had to add Math.multiplyExact, But i figured when there is add there has to be a multiply too, thanks sooo Much man you saved me.

Comment: If this helped then maybe accept the answer so others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to test it as a long.

```
            int max = 2292292;
            int x = 100;
            if ((x + (long)max) != (x + max)) {
                System.out.println("Overflow on x so it wont be printed.");
            } else {
                x = max + 100; 
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quikc feedback.

Comment: Nice it really works, thanks so much now i even know 2 options how to figure this out.

Comment: But  I think for what you want, `sprinter's` solution is cleaner and the way to go.